# E/Volley: [110535] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, android-studio, json, firebase

estoy haciendo una aplicación android con registro y login, y una de las partes es la recuperación de contraseña. 
Para este proceso tengo hecho que cuando se introduzca el correo se le envie un sms con un codigo al numero relacionado, teniendo este servicio gracias a FIREBASE, el problema es que al principio fue sin errores y de repente no me va el metodo y da el error del titulo al pulsar el botón que debe hacer todas las acciones de conexión con firebase, envío de sms y todo lo relacionado.
A continuación pondre el código y el error.

```
package com.example.alex.proyecto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class PassActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseAuth auth;
EditText correo,codigo;
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBack;
String codigoVerificacion;
String numero;
String url = "http://proyectokiriki.000webhostapp.com/devolverCorreo.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pantalla_pass);

    correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoCorreo);
    codigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoCodigo);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            codigoVerificacion = s;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Codigo enviado.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

}

public void enviarSMS(View v) {
    String correoN = correo.getText().toString().trim();


    if (correoN.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes introducir un correo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        AsyncHttpClient cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
        rp.put("correo",correoN);

        cliente.post(url, rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                    String respuesta = response.toString();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Correo correoSMS = gson.fromJson(respuesta, Correo.class);
                    numero = correoSMS.getUsuario().get(0).getTelefono();


            }
        });


        numero = "+34" + numero;
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(numero, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this, mCallBack);

    }
}

public void singInWithPhone(PhoneAuthCredential credential){

    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Intent pass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CambioPassActivity.class);
                String correoN = correo.getText().toString().trim();
                pass.putExtra("correo",correoN);
                finish();
                startActivity(pass);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void verificar(View v){

    String codigoIntroducido = codigo.getText().toString();
    if(!codigoVerificacion.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        verificarNumero(codigoVerificacion,codigoIntroducido);
    }

}

public void verificarNumero(String codigoVerificacion, String codigoIntroducido){

    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codigoVerificacion, codigoIntroducido);
    singInWithPhone(credential);
}
}
```

A continuación pongo lo que sale al pulsar el botón que deberia enviar el sms:

```
2018-11-05 02:06:19.384 6040-6040/com.example.alex.proyecto 

W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@6a4856b
2018-11-05 02:06:19.390 3413-3621/? D/DnsProxyListener: DNSDBG::dns addrinfo af 2
2018-11-05 02:06:19.416 11534-11988/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] PhoneVerificationSession constructor
2018-11-05 02:06:19.419 11534-13980/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
2018-11-05 02:06:19.430 3787-3949/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10024 networkInfo: [type: WIFI[] - WIFI, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "WW 42", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]
2018-11-05 02:06:19.445 11534-23086/? I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyCWF-lLJGTp6i-hRIadiNdEhXk7dZ5JXGY, method: 1 ]
2018-11-05 02:06:19.467 11534-31778/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2018-11-05 02:06:19.467 11534-31778/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2018-11-05 02:06:19.640 11534-31778/? E/Volley: [110535] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyCWF-lLJGTp6i-hRIadiNdEhXk7dZ5JXGY
2018-11-05 02:06:19.641 11534-23086/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER : Invalid format.
2018-11-05 02:06:19.641 11534-11982/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onFailure
2018-11-05 02:06:19.820 11534-13980/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
2018-11-05 02:06:19.993 6040-6040/com.example.alex.proyecto V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 494 from 1 (49400%)
2018-11-05 02:06:19.997 6040-6040/com.example.alex.proyecto W/JsonHttpRH: onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received
    org.json.JSONException: Response cannot be parsed as JSON data
        at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:158)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)

    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Parece que es un error de `Volley`, una biblioteca de Android para conectar con servicios web. Con `Firebase` no necesitas usar `Volley`, ya que FB tiene sus propios mecanismos para enviar y recibir datos. Aunque también tienes una URL a una página web, entonces no entiendo bien si tienes la información en FB o en un servicio web.

Comment: Si, es raro porque que yo sepa no uso nunca Volley, uso los metodos de Firebase directamente, y la información la tengo en una base de datos externa que es de donde cojo los datos, Firebase solo la uso para enviar el sms con el código y comprobarlo.
Por lo que estoy viendo, el fallo esta en que no recibe bien el número de telefono de la base de datos usando el json, y al enviarlo con firebase daba error al ser null.